# Scala zip with id on sorted collections

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have two collections in scala with objects containing id. And I want to zip them together by id. So in such example:

```
case class A(id: Long)
case class B(id: Long)

val col1 = A(1) :: A(2) :: A(5) :: Nil
val col2 = B(2) :: B(2) :: B(5) :: Nil
```

I would expect as result:

```
List(
     (A(1), List()),
     (A(2), List(B(2), B(2)),
     (A(5), List(B(5))
    )
```

How to do it the easy way?
If I know col1 and col2 are already sorted by id would it help somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out a good way to do it without an intermediate variable, but how about something like this:

```
val map = col2.groupBy(_.id).withDefault(_ => List.empty)
col1.map { a => a -> map(a.id) }
```

For 3-element arrays it doesn't matter, but note that the main difference from the other answer is that this is linear time.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to `map` the first collection and inside the `map` do a `filter` on the second and build a tuple:

```
scala> col1.map { c1 =>
     |     (c1, col2.filter(_.id == c1.id))
     |   }
res0: List[(A, List[B])] = List((A(1),List()), (A(2),List(B(2), B(2))), (A(5),List(B(5))))
```